# How do GUI programs determine which construct on the screen was clicked?

Tags: user-interface

A GUI application draws various drawing constructs (texts, buttons, lines etc.) on the screen, and often users are able to click on them. When that happens, how does the program determine the construct to which the very coordinates user clicked on is associated? Does it test if that pixel is inside the construct (what I have in mind is something like [`Shape.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains%28java.awt.geom.Point2D%29) in AWT) for every construct in the program? How is this kind of testing done efficiently when hundreds of different constructs are on the screen (like in browsers or drawing programs such as Inkscape)?

Answer (score 0):

Usually by taking advantage of the hierarchical nature of the on screen elements. First the window containing the click, then the top level panel in that window, then the sub-panel, etc... Even with hundreds of widgets on screen, you can converge very quickly this way, in logarithmic time.